# Driver Manager not resolved in neo4j-jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, neo4j

I am using the neo4j-jdbc-driver for connection to neo4j database in my application. The DriverManager remains unresolved, and I have no idea what package to import for this.

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost");
try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("n.name"));
    }
}
con.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

DriverManager is from the Java JDBC package, i.e. `java.sql.*`

Comment: Thanks for the response. So, DriverManager is taken from java.sql.* but all others like Connection, ResultSet is taken from neoj-java package only. This causes a conflict in types. How to resolve this isssue. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you are misunderstanding the usage of JDBC a little.

`DriverManager` is a class from the `java.sql.*` package and is used (of course) as manager to find the correct class in the application path that shall be used to connect to a specific URL.

The Connection and ResultSet that are giving you problems could be the *internal* neo4j classes, so it might be that you imported the wrong classes.

The classes that you are looking for are also in the `java.sql.*` package.

You can take this as an example:

```
package org.your.package

import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet

public class MyClass {

    public static void main (args[]) {
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:neo4j:bolt://localhost");
        try (Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("MATCH (n:User) RETURN n.name");
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println(rs.getString("n.name"));
            }
        }
        con.close();
    }
}
```